# Picasa data api and JSON - no output

Tags: json, google-plus, picasa

I'm calling my account's album with the URL in following form:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<user_id>/albumid/<album_id>
```

This returns an ATOM feed with this URL:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<user_id>/albumid/<album_id>/?alt=json
```

I get "No album found." error.

Do I have to set up JSON in my account's preferences? Because the method I'm using seems like the proper one - according to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json

Answer (score 0):

This: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/103168604032363426774/albumid/5626814518240219937?alt=json works. It seems like the album you're using doesn't actually exist.

Can you share the URL you're actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Just share album as public.Got to album settings , visible for everyone in the internet